# Неправильно считается дата

Tags: дата, php

Всем привет, у меня проблема: есть конечная дата в Unix - 1353096809 и есть текущее время вызываемое функцией time(), допустим, оно - 1353011685, так вот мне надо высчитать сколько осталось времени до 1353096809 (этой даты). Когда я просто отнимаю:

```
<?=$date_end - time()?>
```

То всё нормально, а когда пытаюсь конвертировать в дату при помощи:

```
<?=date("g:i:s", $date_end - time());?>
```

То мне выводится, что осталось чуть меньше 2-х часов, хотя должно оставаться чуть меньше 23 часов, почему неправильно выводится дата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильный параметр форматирование поставили:

`g` - часы, 12-часовой формат, без первого нуля.

Вам нужен `G` - часы, 24-часовой формат, без первого нуля.

Т.е. :

```
$date_end = 1353096809;
$time = time();
echo date("d-m-Y G:i:s", $date_end);
echo date("d-m-Y G:i:s", $time);
echo date("G:i:s", $date_end - $time);
/* Результат
16-11-2012 23:13:29
16-11-2012 17:20:15
8:53:14
*/
```

Comment: Вот! Спасибо, это то что нужно было!! Спасибо ещё раз :)

Answer (score 5):

Функция    `date`     вторым параметром принимает `timestamp`. В вашем случае просто нужно делить на 60, чтобы узнать сколько минут и еще раз на 60, сколько часов

Comment: Да, но мне нужно получить в итоге примерно такую запись:

12:06:14

часы/минуты/секунды

И я сделал как вы сказали у меня получилось: 375869.478056 - минут...

Answer (score 1):

[date_diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php) Вам в помощь

> `DateTime::diff -- date_diff` — Возвращает разницу между двумя `DateTime` объектами